# No response on Button Click

Tags: java, android, email

I am trying to set up a button for email activity but with current code i get no error but when i click the button there is no response

Email.java

```
public class Email extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText personsEmail, intro, personsName, stupidThings, hatefulAction,
            outro;
    String emailAdd, beginning, name, stupidAction, hatefulAct, out;
    Button sendEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.email);
        initializeVars();
        sendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeVars() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        personsEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmails);
        intro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIntro);
        personsName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        stupidThings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etThings);
        hatefulAction = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAction);
        outro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOutro);
        sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSentEmail);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated();
        String emailaddress[] = { emailAdd };
        String message = "Well hello "
                + name
                + " I just wanted to say "
                + beginning
                + ".  Not only that but I hate when you "
                + stupidAction
                + ", that just really makes me crazy.  I just want to make you "
                + hatefulAct
                + ".  Welp, thats all I wanted to chit-chatter about, oh and"
                + out
                + "Oh and you could visit facebook www.facebook.com/"
                + '\n' + "PS. I think I love you...    ";

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"I hate you");
        emailIntent.setType("Plain/Text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
        startActivity(emailIntent);

    }


    private void convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        emailAdd = personsEmail.getText().toString();
        beginning = intro.getText().toString();
        name = personsName.getText().toString();
        stupidAction = stupidThings.getText().toString();
        hatefulAct = hatefulAction.getText().toString();
        out = outro.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }    
}
```

Menu.java

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Setting Up Button

        Button but1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.bEmail);

         but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.guess.guessme.EMAIL"));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Try to give this line - `sendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);` inside of your method `initializeVars()`

Comment: @mKorbel I have set up the whole layout and everything is done but when i Click the 'Email Me' button i get no response it leads me nowhere

Comment: @SpK the weird part is in my other project the SAME CODING and everything SAME its working perfectly.

Comment: Is your email.xml, the Button "bSentEmail", with the property "onClick" setted? Maybe you should set this property linking it to "onClick" method of your activity

Comment: @SpK its exactly the same. I have copied pasted the code and changed the package name and did suitable changes but in this its not working..let me post my email.xml

Comment: With your debugger can you see what is happening when you click the button?

Comment: @Mike well everything seems perfectly fine with debugger and logcat!

Comment: Can you specifically tell which button is not working in menu activity or in email activity ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code .It may solve your problem:
`startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Email .class));`

Answer (score 0):

try to change your from `emailIntent.setType("Plain/Text");` to `emailIntent.setType("text/html");`
and make following changes may help you

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.guess.guessme.Email"));
```

And make sure, the Email Activity is stated in your Manifest file too.

Comment: I tried that too ! not working and yes obviously i cross checked in Manifest

Comment: Oh, try this: `startActivity(new Intent(this, com.guess.guessme.Email.class))`. This is, because for the Intent constructor you used, the string argument isn't an activities class name, but an Action, which you'd have to specify in Manifest etc. For invoking Activities of your own project, the suggested method is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
 Email.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this -

It seems you're implementing wrong listener. Try try to import `OnClickListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener` Like below -

```
public class Email extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

with below code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

switch(v.getId())
{

case R.id.bSentEmail:

    convertEditTextVarsIntoStringsAndYesThisIsAMethodWeCreated();
    String emailaddress[] = { emailAdd };
    String message = "Well hello "
            + name
            + " I just wanted to say "
            + beginning
            + ".  Not only that but I hate when you "
            + stupidAction
            + ", that just really makes me crazy.  I just want to make you "
            + hatefulAct
            + ".  Welp, thats all I wanted to chit-chatter about, oh and"
            + out
            + "Oh and you could visit facebook www.facebook.com/"
            + '\n' + "PS. I think I love you...    ";

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"I hate you");
    emailIntent.setType("Plain/Text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
    startActivity(emailIntent);

break;
}

}
```

Comment: @Lakshay Narula One more thing? Are you trying this in your device or emulator?

Comment: I tried firstly on my DEVICE cause its email activity and then on device it wasnt working and then on emulator. My first project has EXACT same coding and works fine on device

Comment: @LakshayNarula Actually, which one is not working. Can't you redirect to `Email.java` class?